# MYSQL insert into single table using the results of two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert, myisam

Hello to whomever wishes to bite his teeth on this,

I came across multiple examples of how to use the result set of subquery select into another table.
What I have however is:

```
SELECT `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_id`, `klanten`.`klant_id` 
    FROM `klanten`,`klanten_zakelijk`
    WHERE `klanten`.`emailadres` = '$email' 
    AND `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_kvk`='$kvknr'
```

As you can see I take the results from two different tables and need to port them to another table.

I wish to insert those values into the table `klant_bedrijf_machtiging`.

```
INSERT INTO `klant_bedrijf_machtiging` (`klant_id`, `bedrijfs_id`, `machtiging`) VALUES ('8501', '1', '3');
```

The column `machtiging` is is standard 3 with an insert but I need to be able to change that as well to 1 if the company already exists, but I will intercept that at another part of my code.

All the examples I saw were just the results from one table being imported into anther table.
Does that same logic apply when you take results from two tables? If so, what would be the wisest and most efficient way to implement this?

So to make the question short:
How do I get `bedrijfs_id` and `klant_id` into the corresponding columns into `klant_bedrijf_machtiging` whilst still myself being able to manipulate the last column `machtiging` in just 1 query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! MySQL has an easy way to do this: [MySQL Insert Into w/ Select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

So in your case it would be:

```
INSERT INTO klant_bedrijf_machtiging (`klant_id`, `bedrijfs_id`, `machtiging`)
SELECT `klanten`.`klant_id`, `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_id`, 3
    FROM `klanten`,`klanten_zakelijk`
    WHERE `klanten`.`emailadres` = '$email' 
    AND `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_kvk`='$kvknr'
```

As for changing the item to 1 if it already exists, I am not sure how you would do that in one query without making a huge mess of it.

Comment: I thought that was the right one, I just wasn't sure if that would also be the right way to do it with data from two other tables.
Thanks for confirming my suspicion.
Changing the part to one will be another challenge, but I think i'll intercept that case earlier in the registration process.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets You are welcome. Glad to help. You can use this method with the results of any select query granted the table you are inserting into has the fields. I have used this method with queries with a large number of joins grabbing from 5 - 10 tables depending on how normalized and spread out stuff is. I am glad it exists.

Comment: I can imagine. I wasn't sure this would work because the only thing I could find were one table select examples. Glad you answered so comprehensively.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `klant_bedrijf_machtiging` (`klant_id`, `bedrijfs_id`, `machtiging`)
(SELECT `klanten`.`klant_id`, `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_id`, 3
FROM `klanten`,`klanten_zakelijk`
WHERE `klanten`.`emailadres` = '$email'
AND `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_kvk`='$kvknr')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer :( thank you for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (fields) SELECT `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_id`, `klanten`.`klant_id` 
    FROM `klanten`,`klanten_zakelijk`
    WHERE `klanten`.`emailadres` = '$email' 
    AND `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_kvk`='$kvknr'
```

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: instead to make a comment you can show you appreciation with an upvote

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO klant_bedrijf_machtiging (`klant_id`, `bedrijfs_id`, `machtiging`)
SELECT `klanten`.`klant_id`, `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_id`, 3
    FROM `klanten`,`klanten_zakelijk`
    WHERE `klanten`.`emailadres` = '$email' 
    AND `klanten_zakelijk`.`bedrijfs_kvk`='$kvknr'
```